# Хранимая процедура создания базы данных по шаблону другой базы

Tags: mysql

Можно ли создать хранимую процедуру создания базы данных в MySQL 5.5 по шаблону другой базы (копирование структуры базы данных)?

Создание базы данных через хранимую процедуру работает на ура. Пример:

```
DELIMITER //  
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateDB()    
BEGIN
  CREATE DATABASE `template_test` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
  CREATE TABLE `template_test`.`table_name` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

  INSERT INTO `template_test`.`table_name` (`id`,`name`)
            VALUES (1, "Главная");
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Как должна выглядеть процедура создания базы данных по шаблону другой базы данных?

```
CALL CreateDbLike("template_db_name");
```

Скопировать нужно только структуру.

PS: сделать нужно именно силами SQL, не вызывая `mysqldump` или другие утилиты.

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name; -  структура таблицы в формате "CREATE TABLE"

Comment: @splash58 SHOW CREATE TABLE сохраняет AUTO_INCREMENT. Сбрасывать его приходится вручную. Есть способ сразу получить AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ?

Comment: Для сброса автоинкремента можно выполнить команду `ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;` или `TRUNCATE TABLE table_name;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю следующее решение: извлечь список таблиц из системной таблицы `information_schema`, для каждой из таблиц сформировать оператор `CREATE TABLE` сразу для новой база данных (к сожалению, мы не сможем воспользоваться оператором `SHOW CREATE TABLE`). Далее полученный список строк `CREATE TABLE` обходим курсором и формируем подготовленное выражение (`PREPARE`), которое выполняем.

Для удобства сформируем вспомогательную функцию `columns_build()`, которая будет принимать имя базы данных `db`, имя таблицы `tbl` и формировать список столбцов и их атрибутов через запятую. Сразу оговорюсь, здесь не детальное решение, атрибуты копируются не досконально, если нужна абсолютная точность - эту функцию придется доработать.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS columns_build//
CREATE FUNCTION columns_build (
  `db`   TINYTEXT,
  `tbl`  TINYTEXT
)
RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
  SET @returns = '';
  SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(
      CONCAT(
        c.COLUMN_NAME, ' ',
        c.COLUMN_TYPE, ' ',
        IF(c.IS_NULLABLE, ' NULL ', ' NOT NULL '),
        IF(c.EXTRA = 'auto_increment', 'AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY', '')
      )
      ORDER BY
        c.ORDINAL_POSITION
      SEPARATOR ', '
    ) AS total
  INTO
    @returns
  FROM
    information_schema.COLUMNS AS c
  WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA = db AND TABLE_NAME = tbl
  ORDER BY
    ORDINAL_POSITION;
  IF(SUBSTRING(@returns, -1) = ',') THEN
    RETURN SUBSTRING(@returns, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(@returns) - 1);
  ELSE
    RETURN @returns;
  END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Теперь можно приступить к разработке конечной функции `copy_database()`, которая принимает в качестве первого параметра базу данных источник `olddb`, а в качестве второго - базу данных назначение `newdb`. Здесь мы для краткости тоже немного срезаем углы, предполагая, что движок всех таблиц одинаков и совпадает с заданным по умолчанию для сервера, серверными же настройками задается кодировка баз данных и таблиц.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS copy_database//
CREATE PROCEDURE copy_database(
  IN olddb TINYTEXT,
  IN newdb TINYTEXT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE querystr TEXT DEFAULT '';

  DECLARE curr CURSOR FOR SELECT
    CONCAT(
      'CREATE TABLE ', newdb, '.', t.TABLE_NAME,
      '(', columns_build(olddb, t.TABLE_NAME), ')') AS create_table
  FROM
    information_schema.TABLES AS t
  WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA = olddb;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN curr;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH curr INTO querystr;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    SET @str = querystr;
    -- SELECT @str;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @str;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE curr;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Теперь можно осуществлять копирование таблиц из одной базы данных `test` в другую `newdb`

```
CALL copy_database('test', 'newdb');
```

Comment: Просто Вау! Не думал что эта задача выйдет на две разные процедуры. В mysql явно не хватает `CREATE DATABASE \`dbName\` LIKE \`templateDb\`;`